# SUM incidence matrix - multiply by occurrence

Tags: excel

I have an incidence matrix of values like this:

[image]

- `Col A`: values to be count
- `Col B:C`: occurences of values
- `Cells B1,C1`: `SUM` values in `Col A` if it's `1` in `Col B` (`=SUMIF(B$2:B$5;">=1";$A$2:$A$5)`)

But how to SUM it if I need to use occurence number (1) also as multiplier, like this:

[image]

- i.e. `1*5+2*4+3*1+1*2=18` and `1*5+5*1=10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question :
B1: `=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$5;B2:B5)`
Depending on your regional settings you might need to change the `;` into `,`

Comment: Omg, that's it. Thank you very much!